# How to fix this regex in order to preserve an specific precedence order?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, parsing

I have this large string which is composed of two words and an id:

```
large_string = '''

Aparte aparte RG 0.910714
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
buena bueno AQ0FS0 1
dimension dimension VMIS3P0 0.923476
me me PP1CS000 0.89124
entra entrar VMIP3S0 0.980769
casi casi RG 1
toda todo DI0FS0 0.982026
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
bolsa bolsa NCFS000 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
consorcio consorcio NCMS000 1
entera entero AQ0FS0 0.841237
de de SPS00 0.999984
ropa ropa NCFS000 1
. . Fp 1

El el DA0MS0 1
manual manual NCMS000 0.64261
instructivo instructivo AQ0MS0 1
es ser VSIP3S0 1
bastatnte bastatnte RG 0.557451
específico específico AQ0MS0 0.65727
y y CC 0.999962
```

I would like to extract the second word from left to right and the id that preserve the following order:

```
RN, VA_ _ _ _ _, VMP_ _ _ _ _
```

where `_` are free characters of the id. For example for `large_string` the words and ids that preserve this order are the following:

```
no no RN 
esta estar VASI1S0 
lavando lavar VMP00SM
```

So I would like to generate a regex that catch this order of ids and words, this is what I tried:

```
triple = re.findall(r'(\w+\s+RN).*?(\w+\s+VA\w+).*?(\w+\s+VM\w+)', big_string, re.S)
print weird_triple
```

then:

```
[('no RN', 'error VA00SM', 'utilizar VMN0000'), ('error RN', 'alla VASI1S0', 'lavar VMP00SM')]
```

The problem with this is that the above regex doesnt preserve the order (`RN, VA, VMP` they most be consecutevely). How can I fix it in order to catch only this type of consecutevely word/id. The expected output for this is the following:

Comment: Why is `('no RN', 'error VA00SM', 'utilizar VMN0000')` not correct?  It is certainly order preserving. Is it because `VA00SM` has too few symbols and `VMN0000` doesn't start with `VMP`? In that case, why didn't you make the obvious adjustment to the regular expression? (eg. `VA\w{5}` instead of `VA\w*` and `VMP\w{4}` instead of `VM\w*`)

Comment: They are not correct since they are not consecutive, they doesnt ocurre one after another RN , VA, VMP. They must be consecutive with no other words and ids between them. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I added `error` word be more clear!, thanks guys!

Comment: In that case, you don't want to use `.*?` (which means any sequence of characters, essentially). You want `\n\w+\s+` (which means "a newline character, then a sequence of word characters and a sequence of whitespace). But it depends on how clean your input is; you might want to make the  pattern more flexible. You seem to have some lines which don't correspond to the normal pattern: do you expect them to be ignored, or do they break a sequence? (eg. `, , Fc 1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead beased regex.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?s)(\w+\s+RN)(?:(?!\s(?:RN|VA|VM)).)*?(\w+\s+VA\w+)(?:(?!\s(?:RN|VA|VM)).)*?(\w+\s+VM\w+)', large_string)
[('no RN', 'estar VASI1S0', 'lavar VMP00SM')]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kV8yA9/1)

`(?!\s(?:RN|VA|VM))` Asserts that there isn't a string `<space>` plus `RA` or `VA` or `VM` present on the match. If yes then match the following any character `(?!\s(?:RN|VA|VM)).` , zero or more times `(?:(?!\s(?:RN|VA|VM)).)*?` non-greedily.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I tried this regex and this is what I obtain: `['no RN', 'saber VMII3S0', 'poner VMII3S0', 'error RN', 'accion VMP00SM', 'error VMP00SM', 'conocer VMIS1S0', 'error VA00SM', 'utilizar VMN0000', 'error VA00SM', 'estar VAIP1P0', 'error VMP00RM', 'aprender VMG0000', 'emancipar VMN0000', 'error RN', 'poner VMIP3P0', 'error VMP00RM', 'alla VASI1S0', 'no RN', 'estar VASI1S0', 'lavar VMP00SM']` instead of: `['no RN', 'estar VASI1S0', 'lavar VMP00SM']`. Any idea of how to fix this?